# Syntax error on Heroku on line that doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a Rails app with Haml views which runs fine locally and also on another host. But after deploying to Heroku, the first request gets an error, se the log below:

```
Started GET "/" for 88.159.5.1 at 2012-11-02 07:03:56 +0000
- - Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
- - Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (403.5ms)
- - Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 497ms
- - ActionView::Template::Error (syntax error on line 18, col 4: `all:  all'):                                      
- -     1: .sixteen.columns
- -     2:   #loginblock
- -     3:     .content_title.general
- -     4:     %h2= I18n.t :login_title
- -     5:     .content
- -     6:       = render("layouts/message")
- -     7:       = form_tag(sessions_path, :class => 'form') do
- -   app/views/sessions/new.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_sessions_new_html_haml___1472882735787050115_50827800'
```

Strange thing is: line 18 doesn't exist in that view, it has only 17 lines. And on line 4 I don't see anything wrong? Probably has something to do with Haml or Haml gem not working correctly? See is the view file below. Thanks for any input!

```
.sixteen.columns
  #loginblock
    .content_title.general
    %h2= I18n.t :login_title
    .content
      = render("layouts/message")
      = form_tag(sessions_path, :class => 'form') do
        .field
          = label_tag I18n.t :form_email
          = text_field_tag :email
        .field
          = label_tag I18n.t :form_password
          = password_field_tag :password
        .field
          = submit_tag I18n.t(:login_title), :class => 'button white'
        .clear
```

Comment: I found out the syntax error is coming from the I18n yml file. Commenting the file solves the error, but why does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: the indentation in the yaml file was 4 spaces instead of 2, so a level too deep. For some reason my local Rails setup accepts this, but the Heroku rails setup doesn't. So after correcting the indentation, everything was OK on Heroku.